# Global function and non-static member function pointer design

Tags: c++, templates

I have an continuous optimization algorithm that takes an Oracle function as template parameter. The specific optimization class is defined as:

```
template<class Space, class Solution, class Oracle>
class ConjugateGradient : public ContinuousOptimizerInterface<Space, Solution, Oracle> {
public:

    // Returns the optimal solution found for a given search space
    virtual const Solution& search(const Space& space, Oracle f);
};
```

and as part of the search implementation I have calls to the oracle function:

```
template<class Space, class Solution, class Oracle> 
inline const Solution& ConjugateGradient<Space, Solution, Oracle>::search(const Space& space, Oracle f) {
     // ...
     // get function value and gradient at X
     double fx;
     Solution dfx;
     tie(fx, dfx) = f(X);
     // ..
}
```

A simple example using a global quadratic function:

```
typedef tuple<double, VectorXd> (*oracle_f)(const VectorXd&);
static tuple<double, VectorXd> f(const VectorXd& X) {
     double f = pow((4.0-X(0)), 2) + 10.0;
     VectorXd df = 2.0*X - VectorXd::Ones(X.rows())*8.0;
     return make_tuple(f, df);
}

// ...
ConjugateGradient<TestSpace, VectorXd, oracle_f> optimizer;
VectorXd optimal = optimizer.search(TestSpace(), f);
```

This works OK but now I need to be able to pass a non-static member function of a class as Oracle function to the `ConjugateGradient` algorithm. How do I need to change the `ConjugateGradient` template declaration and implementation for the oracle function to be either a global function or a non-static member function? An alternative approach would be creating a global wrapping function and use varargs to pass arguments through to the wrapping function but this is ugly and not type-safe.

**UPDATE**: This example is using the bind idea of the answer below but using boost::bind instead of std::bind since I'm not on C++11 and std::bind is only available for C++11.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

using namespace Eigen;
using namespace boost;

// the class is parameterized with the appropriate minimizer strategy
enum Minimizer { kNormalEquations, kConjugateGradient };

template <Minimizer M = kNormalEquations>
class SomeANN : AnnInterface {
private:
    // ...
public:
    // define the oracle function type and member function
    typedef tuple<double, VectorXd> (SomeANN::*oracle_f)(const VectorXd&);
    tuple<double, VectorXd> f(const VectorXd& theta);
};

template <>
inline tuple<double, VectorXd> SomeANN<kConjugateGradient>::f(const VectorXd& theta) {
    double f = 0.0;
    VectorXd df;
    return make_tuple(f, df);
}

// ridge solver using conjugate gradient
template <>
inline void SomeANN<kConjugateGradient>::ridge_solve(const VectorXd& Y) {
    ConjugateGradient<BeginSpace, VectorXd, SomeANN::oracle_f> optimizer;
    // ...
    optimizer.search(BeginSpace(Y.rows()), boost::bind(&SomeANN::f, this, _1));
}
```

then I get the error:

```
some_ann.h:163:84: error: no matching function for call to 'ConjugateGradient<BeginSpace, Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1>, boost::tuples::tuple<double, Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1> > (SomeANN<(Minimizer)1u>::*)(const Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1>&)>::search(BeginSpace, boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::tuples::tuple<double,  Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1> >, boost::_mfi::mf1<boost::tuples::tuple<double, Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1> >, SomeANN<(Minimizer)1u>, const Eigen::Matrix<double, -0x00000000000000001, 1>&>,  boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<SomeANN<(Minimizer)1u>*>, boost::arg<1> > >)'
conjugate_gradient.h:67:2: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'f (...)', e.g. '(... ->* f) (...)'
conjugate_gradient.h:84:3: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'f (...)', e.g. '(... ->* f) (...)'
conjugate_gradient.h:111:5: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'f (...)', e.g. '(... ->* f) (...)'
conjugate_gradient.h:153:4: error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in 'f (...)', e.g. '(... ->* f) (...)'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/some_ann_library.dir/main/cpp/some_ann.cc.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/some_ann_library.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change search, pass a bind expression:

```
auto& solution = cg.search(space, std::bind(
    &MyType::member_function, &myInstance, std::placeholders::_1));
```

Comment: One side note is that for this to work I need C11 and I don't currently. I'm on GNU MacPorts gcc46 4.6.3_9

Comment: 4.6's -std=c++0x mode doesn't have std::bind?